# Как написать такой .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как написать в правило .htaccess, чтобы при заходе на сайт  переправляло на public/index.php

Comment: на любую страницу, или только на главную?

Comment: на любую страницу

Comment: Как я понял тут нюанс, который автор не учел, перенаправление должно сработать единожды и дальше пользователь может гулять по сайту нормально. Я правильно понял?

Comment: да правильно понял .

Answer (score 1):

```
# Это покажет /public/index.php , если зашли на главную
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
```